# Converting floating values to datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I am having a problem converting a floating point values to correct date time. I have tried in Excel, I could do it easily.

For example :

I have a floating value of 42075.6111 which is equivalent to 12-Mar-15 14:39. Is there a way I could use easily implement in python ?

I am trying the datetime module as like this :

```
import datetime
mydate=42075.6111
offset=693960
datetime.date.fromordinal((dateoffset+mydate))
```

Its giving an error msg : integer argument expected

Is there a easy module which can handle floating dataset, as we can easily do in Matlab

Comment: What does the floating point number represent? is it seconds from the epoch? i.e. Unix time